# Ubuntu minimal cd size after installation?

Tags: 14.04, ubuntu-minimal

So I downloaded ubuntu ubuntu 14.04.3 mini.iso.
I installed the ubuntu on virtual box.

Now after the installation the size used on the virtual hdd is 2.15GB??

Did I do something wrong? My goals was that I get a minimal installation with the mini.iso which size would be a few hundred MB.

I didnt check any additional packages to be installed only the basic ubuntu was checked but a file /dev/sda1 has a size of 1.1GB and udev has 361MB. now i am interested what is the actual size of the ubuntu operating system in this case and what is /dev/sda1

So can this be any smaller? more compact after installation?

Comment: The `mini.iso` is for network-based installation. It contains only installation-essential packages and downloads the rest from the internet. Which it presumably did, in your case. Which software did you choose to install during the setup?

Comment: i chose none, i wanted to install the bare minimum, but a file /dev/sda1 has a size of 1.1GB and udev has 361MB. now i am interested what is the actual size of the ubuntu operating system in this case and what is /dev/sda1 :)

Comment: is there a command to check the ubuntu operating system size with the packages installed and used?

Comment: After installation? Run `df -h /` to find the size and `dpkg -l | grep ii` to find installed packages.

Comment: df -h / says used size 1.1G, thats kinda too much still not sure what sda1 is and why it has a size 1.1G